# Which MacBook Pro should I get?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I'm going to buy a MacBook Pro to use at University (Studying Computer Science). I've been using a Mid-2013 MacBook Air for the last year.

Current machine: Mid-2013 MacBook Air, 4GB RAM, 128GB SSD, core i5.

I'm stuck between the 13 inch MacBook Pro without TouchBar with 16GB RAM, 256GB SSD, i5 Processor and the 13 inch MacBook Pro with TouchBar with 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, i7 Processor.

For a machine that'll be used primarily for programming and video editing would the faster processor or more RAM be worth it?

I don't particularly want the TouchBar, but the TouchBar model has more ports.

Also, would the TouchBar model with the faster processor have worse battery life due to the TouchBar and the faster clock speed?

Would you notice a speed difference with the processor because only when video editing do I currently max out my machine?

The price is also a concern, it's annoyingly expensive as it is.
Is the base model with no TouchBar, 8GB RAM, core i5, 2 ports but with the 256GB SSD worth the money?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This is not a shopping site...